# Looking for an algorithm to locate 2D shapes closest as possible to one another - so their combined shape envelope would be minimal?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry, area

In other words If I would need to surround them with a rope.. it would be the shortest rope.

For example lets say we have following shapes:

[shapes before algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvpgN.png)

Then after algorithm we will get something like this:

[after algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6O9P.png)

Thank you in advanced,
N-B

Comment: This is extremely difficult.

Comment: I did a search for "2d packing minimize convex hull" and it seems people have solved this for circles but not much more complex shapes. If your shapes are "fat" (close to circles) and you're okay with approximations, you might be able to get acceptable results by wrapping each shape in a circle and solving that?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele - yes it would be great - to act is if we have circles. Thank you.

Any specific articles/algorithms on that?

Thank you,

Comment: This looked somewhat relevant but pretty intimidating too https://users.astro.ufl.edu/~kallrath/files/KallrathFrey-2019.pdf And it doesn't seem to be a very fast solution, so if you're hoping for anything (near) real-time, there probably isn't any existing solution. But I'm absolutely no expert in this field, so don't trust too much on my gut feeling :)